# aws - route request via application load balancer based on subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have AWS question

My goal is to route requests to a group (include ec2 servers) based on a subdomain.

For the solution, I have router53 and an application load balancer.

How it should work:

I have two subdomains that both are registered I the router 53 and assigned to the application load balancer (the request will be forwarded to the application load-balancer)

Users.example.com
Servers.example.com

When the browser issue request to http://Users.example.com the application load-balancer should route the traffic to ec2 servers under group a

When the browser issue request to **https**://servers.example.com the application load-balancer should route the traffic to ec2 servers under group b

Is this can be achieved with the following objects:
router53 and application load-balancer.  If so, can you explain in a high level what should be the rule in the load balancer the looking for the subdomain?

If not, is there another solution that I can implement (basically I'm looking to implement a solution using AWS resources instead of development)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Specifically, you have to create **two target groups** for your ALB. One for servers in group A, and the second for servers in group B.

Then you setup [host-based routing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-configure-host-based-routing-alb/) in your listeners for `Users.example.com` and `Servers.example.com`. Depending on the host, you forward requests to the corresponding target group.